# Floating point arithmetic rounding to nearest

Tags: math, floating-point

I am a little confused about rounding to nearest in floating point arithmetic. Let a, b, and c be normalized double precision floating point numbers. Is it true that a+b=b+a where + is correctly rounded to nearest floating point addition? My initial guess is yes this is always true, but I don't completely understand rounding to nearest. Could someone give an example of when a+b != b+a using floating point addition with rounding to nearest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Properly implemented IEEE-754 floating-point addition is commutative (a+b equals b+a) regardless of rounding mode.

The rounding mode affects how the exact mathematical result is rounded to fit into the destination format. Since the exact mathematical results of a+b and b+a are identical, they are rounded identically.

Comment: I see. Is it also associative? For example, does (a+b)+c = a+(b+c)?

Comment: @SKLAK: No.  Easy counterexample: `a = 1e16, b = -1e16, c = 1`.

Comment: Arithmetic is not associative because changing the order of operations changes where rounding errors occur. E.g., the computed `(a+b)+c` and `a+(b+c)` are mathematically `f(f(a+b)+c)` and `f(a+f(b+c))`, where `f` is the function that rounds an exact mathematical value to a value representable in floating-point. There is generally no reason that `f(a+b)` will have the same rounding error as `f(b+c)`, so these may produce different results.

Answer (score 0):

As noted above, addition is commutative but not associative. The difference in rounding modes can be seen by running the following (MS Visual Studio) C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <float.h>

#pragma fenv_access(on)

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    float a = 1.75f, b = 1e-6f;

    cout.setf(ios::fixed,ios::floatfield);
    cout.precision(7);

    cout << "a = " << a << ", b = " << b << endl;

    _controlfp_s(NULL, _RC_DOWN,_MCW_RC);

    cout << "Result of a + b rounded down: " << a+b << endl;
    cout << "Result of a - b rounded down: " << a-b << endl;

    _controlfp_s(NULL, _RC_UP,_MCW_RC);
    cout << "Result of a + b rounded up: " << a+b << endl;
    cout << "Result of a - b rounded up: " << a-b << endl;

    _controlfp_s(NULL, _RC_NEAR,_MCW_RC);
    cout << "Result of a + b rounded to nearest: " << a+b << endl;
    cout << "Result of a - b rounded to nearest: " << a-b << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
a = 1.7500000, b = 0.0000010
Result of a + b rounded down: 1.7500010
Result of a - b rounded down: 1.7499989
Result of a + b rounded up: 1.7500011
Result of a - b rounded up: 1.7499990
Result of a + b rounded to nearest: 1.7500010
Result of a - b rounded to nearest: 1.7499990
```